# Play a Youtube video in a fragment

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am working on an app. This app uses a Master-/Detail-View.

After selecting an video in the Master-View I want to play a video in the Detail-View. 
Currently I focus on the tablet version, which means, I want to play a yt-video in the detail-fragment.

How can I do this?

//edit:
The default code uses `getSupportFragmentManager()` and I tried to put a normal `YouTubePlayerFragment`.
Either use `getFragmentManager()` or use `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`. This fixed my issue.

Comment: have your tried using WebView inside the detail-fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The youtube API provides the [YoutubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) to play youtube video in a fragment.

Also, Youtube API provides the [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) based on `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to earlier versions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I read about this before. I'll edit my fix in my question